# How to add echarts markpoint to chart for show specific events

Tags: echarts

I want to add echarts markpoint to chart for show specific events, as the figure below. I expect that I can add event on specific date. And when user hover event block(D), they can see tooltip about some details.

I tried to use echarts markpoint option to add event block, but I don't know how to get hover event to show tooltip. And I want to add event to specific data, but now I just can set it position by (x, y). Or Is there any way/option to solve my problem? Thank you!

```
markPoint: {
  symbol: 'rect',
  symbolSize: 15,
  label: {
    formatter: 'D',
  },
  itemStyle: {
    color: 'rgba(70,78,86,.9)',
  },
  data: [
    { x: 70, y: 140 },
  ],
},
```

- actual result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MitaC.png

- expected result

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLTzz.png

Comment: How about using tooltip with axis trigger? http://echarts.apache.org/option.html#tooltip.trigger

Comment: Hi Ovilia, thanks for your comment. But it still can't help me to solve my problem. I have tooltip of two types. When I hover markPoint, not show data of axis. https://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/mix10.html

Comment: I believe this is the way ECharts does. There's no easy way to get what you want. But you can use extra DOM or using ECharts graphics to draw the tooltip you want.

Answer (score 1):

[Tooltip formatter](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.tooltip.formatter) function of the `markPoint` can be used to entirely configure what should be shown.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAlgWwOYwLwwEoHksBUD6ACgIK4ASMA1DAOQD0AJgIZRN1MQQCmUdiSdAO5cWACy4AnOhACuYMAE98ARgBMADgB0ABzBIaAbgBQRkNqhxwaGAG8jMGAA9ijuBABct-w5hQF2rk8aYBYuJBAJBRoAGm8HZlZPAG0aAFlwGNpcGS5MmgB1LgY83FEZPIAxCTg8gGUWOrkaAF1vAF9YhygQEAAbC21PGw7vBRc3Ibjff0DaADcmXpyads6YbmquDxgkqbsfHwSmZOUAVgAGaJhVAGZL69UAFivVZXUr5RvTj8eAdheAGznZprA5-AJBXpwMC5UE-BBMCQAa0IIGhUEmBwOEAUCAARn0ghAAI4yRGwqbY3EE3q1OAAL1mdzhB16TDxXF6mKxBwAZuAoHTGZ5lACWVjQL0IkFBKI4FBcpSfCMeQ55VwELU_L1ZvtVQ5JdLaEgJFwouKHCrVUdkkqDjZQBEGMlVNFlOdgVcFktZjQACI0K08kF23w9fpwQa2fkSBFQBUSTwK6BtJWpg7pmCtNrGEwmXlyYAWKzJqAACm0iKYCAgAEovA5TVAZBIwLQADwMOBzAB8Dnb2j74lNMBCbY5MCYiigcr0MAUIBkMEEU9g7bog5g7bxEj725k8as0AUOtQACJDYmYKaGAYz32ICAEFxfFxHGu6HiD90wHuu72aCoGAphodt-HWCRgFQQDqHA6gaB7FY2iAA):

```js
const img = ROOT_PATH + '/data/asset/img/weather/sunny_128.png';

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  tooltip: {},
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line',
      markPoint: {
        symbol: 'square',
        symbolSize: 30,
        label: {
          fontSize: 16,
          color: 'white'
        },
        itemStyle: {
          color: 'grey',
        },
        data: [
          {coord: [2,100], value: 'D'},
        ],
        tooltip: {formatter: test}
      }
    }
  ]
};


function test(params) {
  return '<div> <p> here can be anything you want </p> <br> <button style="color: red;"> some text </button> <div>' + 
    '<img src=' + img + '>'
}
```